# Restricting who can deregister AMI based on a Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Is it possible to restrict who can deregister an AMI via IAM? The criteria I want to use is a tag attached to the image resource. The Tag is "ReleaseStage" and the values are "Beta", "RC" and "GA"... IAM users that are in the Developer group should not be allowed to deregister a "GA" tagged AMI.

Is this possible and if so what kind of IAM policy document would I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS documentation has an example showing the use of a tag in a condition for a policy in

- *[Allow Users to Manage Amazon EBS Volumes and Amazon EC2 Instances That Have the Specified Tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-ec2-tag-permissions)*.

In the given example, the relevant line is

```
"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/volume_user": "${aws:username}"}}
```

where `volume_user` is the name of the tag in the example, and the expression `${aws:username}` is the value against which it is compared.

Conditions are documented starting here:

- *[IAM Policy Elements Reference: Condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition)*

Your condition would look like

```
"Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/ReleaseStage": "GA"}}
```

and you would use it in a policy whose effect is "deny", attaching the policy to the "developers" group.  The policy itself would look like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:DeregisterImage",
      "Condition": {"StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/ReleaseStage": "GA"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions), "Condition" are not supported for action "ec2:DeregisterImage". The solution proposed by @Thomas Dickey does not work for me, and I haven't find any other solution to do this.